# Dropbox core api: is rev unique?

Tags: dropbox-api

I am using the dropbox core api currently.
For each object, I tried to use the rev value as the uri.
However, from the document of dropbox and result of google, I am not sure whether the rev is a unique number or not.

```
file.rev // and results is something like: 7e91b4dee3f
```

Can anyone confirm this?
Great Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unique across what? It uniquely identifies a revision *of that file*.

Answer (score 0):

[Further info](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Rev-in-the-Path/td-p/179160) on this from Dropbox:

"The rev value uniquely identifies the file in the Dropbox, including path, so you don't need to add a path too."